# Find the dimensions of some kernel subspaces of $\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a bit unconfident with the following proof that I made to find the dimensions of the subspace below,

$$
S =\{T\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W): T(v)=0\}
$$
where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over F of dimensions $n$ and $m$ respectively and $v\in V$ be a non-zero vector. What I did is to define the following,
$$
U:\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\rightarrow W
$$
where $T\mapsto T(v)$. And show $U$ is a linear transformation, then using the Dimension Theorem to find the $\operatorname{dim}(S)$ since $S=\operatorname{ker}(U)$. To show $U$ is linear is not so difficult, but I was confused at the end that was whether if $\operatorname{Im}(U)=W$. I know $\operatorname{Im}(U)\subset$ W, but if $\operatorname{Im}(U)\neq W$, then I can't derive the conclusion such that $\operatorname{dim}(S)= nm-m$.

Additionally, I also have the following question that is to find the possible dimensions of the subspace below,
$$
C =\{T\in\operatorname{Hom}(V,W):T(v_1)=0,T(v_2)=0,T(v_3)=0\}
$$
where $v_1,v_2,v_3\in V$. Basically, I show this in a similar way to the previous one. Let
$$
\Phi:\operatorname{Hom}(V, W)\rightarrow W\times W\times W
$$
which is defined differently depending on the independence of $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, but to show all of them are linear is not so difficult either. For example, if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent then $\Phi:T\mapsto (T(v_1),T(v_2),T(v_3))$. Since $C=\operatorname{ker}(\Phi)$ and if $\operatorname{Im}(\Phi)=W\times W\times W$, then using Dimension Theorem $\operatorname{dim}(C)=nm-3m$. Similarily, depending on the dependence between $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$, I can also derive two possible dimensions that are $\operatorname{dim}(C)=nm-2m$ or $\operatorname{dim}(C)=nm-m$.

I wonder how to end the proof (e.g. how to tell $\operatorname{Im}(U)=W$?), and whether if my guesses to the second question is correct or not.

PS: I am a newcomer to linear algebra so if I made anything unclear or wrong in the proof, please help me to point it out since this is helpful for me to improve my skill when writing a proof.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ for $V$ such that $v_1=v$ (this can be done since $v \neq 0$). Then, for each $w \in W$, let $T_w \in \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ be the linear map such that $$T_w(a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n) = a_1w$$ for every  $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in F^n$ (this is well-defined, since each element of $V$ can be written in a unique way as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$).

Then $w = T_w(v) = U(T_w) \in \operatorname{im} U$, and since $w$ was arbitrary, it follows that $W = \operatorname{im} U$.

Now, use a similar argument to finish the second problem!

Comment: So what you mean is that for any $w\in W$, we can always have a specific $T_w\in \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)$ such that $T_w\mapsto T_w(v)=w$ for some $v\in V$? But why this $T_w$ always exist? Can you evaluate a bit at this point? Thanks.

Comment: Sure!  I just edited my answer.

Comment: But for the second question, I state that a possible dimension is $ab - 2b$. However, if $ab<2b$ doesn't this imply that the $\operatorname{Im}(\Phi)\neq W$? Because otherwise $\operatorname{nullity}(\Phi)<0$.

Comment: My question has just been resolved. Thank you for your contribution. Have a good day.

Comment: @oscarmetalbreak Wonderful. By the way, in the second problem there are four posibilities: if $j = \dim(\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\})$ (so $j \in \{0,1,2,3\}$), then the dimension of $C$ is $nm-jm$. Sorry about that, I just realized.

Answer (score 1):

Any element in Hom(V, W) is a map from V to W.

v is a fixed element in V.

Thus for any w∈W, we can define a Tw: V -> W which map v to w regardless of what Tw map other elements of V to

This Tw always exists since it belongs to the set Hom(V, W)

This implies that Image(U)=W

Comment: Thanks for your comment.